# Custom item prices change in WooC

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Have situation with custom price for item line in WooC.
Now find solution to change subtotal in Edit of order this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_order_item', function ($_item_id, $_item, $_order_id) {
    if( $arr_item_meta = wc_get_order_item_meta($_item_id) )
    {
        $prc = wooc_item1_price( $arr_item_meta["_a1"][0], $arr_item_meta["_a2"][0], $arr_item_meta["_a3"][0], $_item->get_product()->get_id() );
      $_item -> set_total( $prc );
            $_item -> set_subtotal( $prc );
            $_item -> save();
    } 
  },10,3);
```

This only works on edit. I.e. while updated - it set up price i make with function

wooc_item1_price with few argumens from cart (quantities of each type of product)

---

Problem is:

howto make same after product just added to cart. 
So new subtotal+total will be available in order before any edit/updater.
Please help me!

Comment: Please look carefully:

it set up price i make with function
wooc_item1_price with few argumens from cart (quantities of each type of product)

Comment: One of ides is - to use woocommerce_calculate_totals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action ('woocommerce_calculate_totals', function( $_cart )
{
    foreach ($_cart->cart_contents as $cart_key => $cart_item) 
    {
    $prc = function_to_make_item_custom_price(
        $_cart->cart_contents[$cart_key]["_param1"],
        $_cart->cart_contents[$cart_key]["_param2"],
        $_cart->cart_contents[$cart_key]["_param3"],
        $_cart->cart_contents[$cart_key]["product_id"]
      );

        $_cart->cart_contents[$cart_key]['line_subtotal'] = $prc;
        $_cart->cart_contents[$cart_key]['line_total']    = $prc;
    }             
}, 10,1);
```

this is right way - make price on adding item to cart. 
is need have price function  function_to_make_item_custom_price to make custom price, based on parameters. In my case - this is quantites of product parts (tour adult&child&infants param1,param2,param3)

Its simplifed idea, is need also recal taxes, coupons ...